# Swift UITextField to match array of strings if user types lower case

Tags: swift, swift2

I have an array of strings, and as a user types into a text field I want it to check against the array to see if there is a match. This works fine if the user types in the proper case..ie. Potter ...but if the user typed in potter it would not find a match. I know how to convert it to lowercase but I want it to display the proper case in the end Potter

This is what i tried

```
func tempConvertToLowerCase(){

    let nowLowerCaseTextFieldInput = textField.text
    nowLowerCaseTextFieldInput?.lowercaseString

    var nowLowerCaseArrayEach : String?

    for key in autoCompletePossibilities {
        if key == textField.text?.lowercaseString {
            nowLowerCaseArrayEach = key.lowercaseString
            print ("it worked")
        }
    }


}
```

**Update**

I have tried this and still I cannot get my code to work

```
 func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    let substring = (textField.text! as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)


    if textField == textField{
        let newText = range.length == 0 ? textField.text! + string : (textField.text! as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)

        if autoCompletePossibilities.contains({$0.caseInsensitiveCompare(newText) == .OrderedSame}) {

            print("it worked")
        }

    }




    return true

}
```

Comment: `nowLowerCaseTextFieldInput?.lowercaseString` you are not assigning the value returned to any variable at all. try `let nowLowerCaseTextFieldInput = textField.text!.lowercaseString`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if text.caseInsensitiveCompare(anotherText) == .OrderedSame
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if textField.text!.lowercaseString == originalString.lowercaseString {
```

You can just use `.lowercaseString` to compare the 2 strings.

Comment: @RubberDucky4444 could you please be more specific by "not working"

Comment: I apologize I had to run (on mobile now) I will be more specific when I get back

Comment: I updated my question to show what I tried and after trying both results here. I am still not having any luck.